# How to send Email with PhpMailer and WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, phpmailer, wampserver

I dont know what else to do to make email sending works using phpmailer and WampServer. I have configured WAMP just as a I read in a lot of forums, but I cant make it work. I have this example:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    //envia correo desde el servidor local (pruebas)
    include("clases/class.phpmailer.php");
    include("clases/class.smtp.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Username = "restofinder2016@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "****";

    $mail->From = "restofinder2016@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Resto";
    $mail->Subject = "Subject del Email";
    $mail->AltBody = "Hola, te doy mi nuevo numero\nxxxx.";
    $mail->MsgHTML("Hola, te doy mi nuevo numero<br><b>xxxx</b>.");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("files/files.zip");
    //$mail->AddAttachment("files/img03.jpg");
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], "user name");
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    }

    //fin enviar correo usuando servidor local  
}
?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" />
    </p>
</form>
```

I was told that it doesnt work with gmail, that I should use some other kind of mail. I get this error:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

What can I do to make it work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you see this : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: Here we go again....assuming it's for a personal project and that you are learning php from scratch, then it is ok to use an external email account in order to send test emails....but still mmmmm...it should be better to start learning some basic OOP concepts, and then moving on to a php framework like laravel or codeigniter(I recommend this one for beginners)

Comment: It looks like you're using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an obsolete (and wrong) example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and read the docs.

Comment: mm, i`m starting to think that it`s related to firewall or something like that.. anyway, does anyone have any tutorial so that I can check if a have configured everything fine? I mean any forum or page that explains how to configure wamp properly, maybe I have read it from incomplete sources. By the way, thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

uncommented in php.ini

And change

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

to

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

as your are using tls port for ssl (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229)

If both of them don't help add

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

It will show you more details about the problem

Comment: Hi, I changed it as you suggested, the error now says:                     SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder. (10060)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Answer (score 0):

Try this port

```
$mail->Port = 465;
```

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I tried this too, but did not work yet :S

Comment: you have to change your sendmail configuration then it will work.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me: https://websistent.com/using-sendmail-on-windows/ Just instead of this part "smtp_server=ssl://smtp.gmail.com" I set this way: "smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com".